# php mail not receiving the message

Tags: php, html, email, email-validation

I'm not receiving the text from the form field. Anything im doing wrong ?

```
<?php
$newsletter_email = $_POST['newsletter_email'];
$to = "gb@gyde.asia";
$subject = "Subscription for Newsletter";
$headers = "From: $to";
mail ($to, $subject, " E-mail: " . $newsletter_email, $headers);
if(mail ($to, $subject, " E-mail: " . $newsletter_email, $headers )){ 
echo "Mail did its job..."; } else { echo "Oops, something went South!";  }
?>
```

### HTML

```
    <div id="newsletter" class="form-wrap"> 
        <form action="process.php" method="post" id="newsletter-form"> 
            <input type="text" name="newsletter_email" id="newsletter_email" required class="feedback-input" maxlength="30" placeholder="Email" /> 
            <input type="submit" name="newsletter_submit" id="newsletter_submit" value="Subscribe" class="button-blue"/> 
        </form> 
    </div>
```

---

Comment: Check spam box, and by the way you're sending email twice

Comment: @HankyPanky Im receiving the email but not the text from form.

Comment: Then you're probably not POSTing it correctly. Can we see your HTML?

Comment: where did the POST ?

Comment: <div id="newsletter" class="form-wrap">
     <form action="process.php" method="post" id="newsletter-form">
         <input type="text" name="newsletter_email"  id="newsletter_email" required class="feedback-input" maxlength="30" placeholder="Email" />
         <input type="submit" name="newsletter_submit" id="newsletter_submit" value="Subscribe" class="button-blue"/>
     </form>
    </div>

Comment: @HankyPanky im using id="newsletter_email"

Comment: @AneequeAhmed - Edit you post, not here in the comment

Comment: 'id' does not get posted, `name` does

Comment: @LorenzoBelfanti ok i have edited the post, i have added html code.

Comment: @HankyPanky but the name is also newsletter_email :)

Comment: @HankyPanky - `name` and `id` can coexist with same value

Comment: @LorenzoBelfanti when did i say they can't?

Comment: @AneequeAhmed, you are sending mail using localhost  ?

Comment: @Ms.Nehal no, im using namecheap domain & hosting

Comment: @AneequeAhmed, there might be issue with your mail server. Try it using SMTP, or check mail settings in `php.ini` file

Comment: @Ms.Nehal SMTP is also not allowed. Where can i find php.ini file ?

Comment: @AneequeAhmed, on the root of your server, if not then ask your host provider for this

Answer (score 0):

You scripts is fine, but you send mail **twice**. 
Before send check if the `POST` have some message to send.
Change like this:

```
$newsletter_email = $_POST['newsletter_email'];
if($newsletter_email != ""){
    $to = "gb@gyde.asia";
    $subject = "Subscription for Newsletter";
    $headers = "From: $to";
    if(mail ($to, $subject, " E-mail: " . $newsletter_email, $headers ))
    { 
         echo "Mail did its job..."; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
         echo "Oops, something went South!"; 
    }
}
```

**N.B**. Check your Spam Box as said *Hanky Panky*

Comment: It still not receiving the text from the form field. but yeah i was sending it twice. $newsletter_email is not working, any advice ?

Comment: @AneequeAhmed - I'm looking at the **HTML** where did that `$email_newsletter` but it seems to me entirely correct

Comment: Im using namecheap hosting, and their mail function is different.

Answer (score 0):

Some time Mail function does not support your server. so mail can't reach.

There is a solutions please use SMTP mail.

```
<?php
    ini_set("SMTP", "aspmx.l.google.com");
    ini_set("sendmail_from", "YOURMAIL@gmail.com");

    $message = "The mail message was sent with the following mail setting:\r\nSMTP = aspmx.l.google.com\r\nsmtp_port = 25\r\nsendmail_from = YourMail@address.com";

    $headers = "From: YOURMAIL@gmail.com";


    mail("Sending@provider.com", "Testing", $message, $headers);
    echo "Check your email now....<BR/>";
?>
```